# OpenLayers: png as external graphic marker

Tags: openlayers-2, png, markers

I would like to style my point features. For some markers I use the convenient OpenLayers.StyleMap options, for few of them I would like to use an external png graphic (the camouflage circle). I use a linux system and the firefox browser. The code runs pretty if I leave out the external graphic. If I add the graphic the feature disappears. Is there something specific I have to consider? Any help is welcome.

[image]

This graphic has the size of 14.2 KiB and was edited with the Vector Graphics Editor. 
My code so far is:

```
var styleMap = new OpenLayers.StyleMap({
            "default": new OpenLayers.Style({
                graphicName: "cross",
                pointRadius: "5", // sized according to type attribute
                fillColor: '#FF8000',
                fillOpacity: "50 ",  //o.8 original
                strokeOpacity: "60", //1 original
                strokeWidth: "1",
                },
                { // apply a rule in order to display a name next to the station point in legend
                rules : [
                        new OpenLayers.Rule({
                        name: "Stations", // this is what is displayed on legend panel
                        elseFilter: true,
                        symbolizer: {
                            graphicName: "cross",
                            pointRadius: "5",
                            fillColor: "#FF8000",
                            strokeOpacity: "60",
                            strokeWidth: "1",
                            }
                        }),
                        new OpenLayers.Rule({
                            name: "Climate, Soil & Water Quality",
                            filter: new OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison({
                                        type: OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison.LIKE,
                                        property: "name",                                                            
                                        value: "Zarnekow",
                                    }),
                                    symbolizer: {                
                                                externalGraphic: "../img/point_camouflage1.png",// graphicName: "circle",         
                                                graphicWidth: 32,
                                                graphicHeight: 32,
                                                graphicOpacity:1,//pointRadius: "5",
                                                //fillColor: "#F27807",
                                                //strokeOpacity: "60",
                                                //strokeWidth: "1",
                                    }       
                            })
                          ]
                       })
                });
```

Comment: are you sure that the directory ../img is available from your browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried to move the graphic to the same folder or a subfolder?

or use an absolute adress
http://jsfiddle.net/ucrtthya/

and don't forget to load the website with the http protocol, like http://localhost/mymap.html
otherwise it could perhaps be a problem if you open the webpage with "file///" and try to load a image with the "http://"-protocol

Comment: I am 100% sure the folder path is ok. I use a Apache server, so I also use the http:// protocol. I also tried a svg. Nothing.

Comment: It works just with you absolute adress "https://i.stack.imgur.com/ynyjz.png". But why not relative?

Comment: perhaps some read permissions issues? have you tried to move the png into the same folder as your js-file and use externalGraphic: "point_camouflage1.png"  ? or use the local adress http://localhost/yourfolder/img/point_camouflage1.png". I have sometimes encountered problems in the past when the image was in folders "above" the app ( ../ )

Comment: I tried to move the png to the same folder as my js. Nothing. But I can call it from the local adress into the browser as you mentioned. The "img" folder is one folder below the js folder. I am pretty sure that I have reading permissions for that specific folder.

Comment: NOW! I understand what you meant.I don't now why I does not work the way I did before, but now it works apparently with the local address. externalGraphic: "http://localhost/Stations/Europe/img/point_camouflage1.png". Thank you Thomas!

Answer (score 0):

in your Javascript there are two brackets missing at the end.
perhaps that's the problem. see
http://jsfiddle.net/po6m5aok/2/

Comment: That's true. But it still does not work as I wish.I corrected the line.